# Making new list of lists from elements of some other lists

Tags: python, list

I have below list of lists:

```
Points = [['A', 1.01, 0.11], ['B', 0.97, 0.14], ['C', 1.05, 0.15], ['D', 0.96, 0.14], ['E', 1.55, 0.22], ['F', 1.06, 0.04], ['G', 0.88, 0.15], ['H', 0.80, 0.21], ['I', 0.87, 0.19], ['J', 0.80, 0.30]]

Origin = [['J', 0.80, 0.30]]

Distance = [0.28, 0.23, 0.30, 0.22, 0.75, 0.37, 0.17, 0.09, 0.13, 0.0]
```

I need to take 1st element of lists in the Point List,
1st element of list in the Origin List,
and the distance from Distance List.

How can I make a new list like this with Python?

```
Span = [['A', 'J', 0.28], ['B', 'J', 0.23], ['C', 'J', 0.30], ['D', 'J', 0.22], ['E', 'J', 0.75], ['F', 'J', 0.37], ['G', 'J', 0.17], ['H', 'J', 0.09], ['I', 'J', 0.13], ['J', 'J', 0.00]]
```

I have tried below

```
Point_Name=[(i[0]) for i in Points]
Origin_Set=[(i[0]) for i in Origin]
Span = zip(Point_Name,Origin_Set,Distance)
print Span
```

but it didn't work out as I need it. as i got only one list:

```
[('A', 'J', 0.28)]
```

Comment: @JulienBernu thank you for your reminder, I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pythonic implementation.

```
[i.append(Origin[0][0]) for i in Points]
print [[item1[0],item1[-1],item2] for item1,item2 in zip(Points,Distance)]
```

**Result**

```
[['A', 'J', 0.28], ['B', 'J', 0.23], ['C', 'J', 0.3], ['D', 'J', 0.22], ['E', 'J', 0.75], ['F', 'J', 0.37], ['G', 'J', 0.17], ['H', 'J', 0.09], ['I', 'J', 0.13], ['J', 'J', 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

```
list = []
for i in range(len(Points)):
    element = []
    element.append(Points[i][0])
    element.append(Origin[0][0])
    element.append(Distance[i])
    list.append(element)
print list
```